# How to remain on the same page when I click on add to cart button in category page

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, shopping-cart, addtocart

When I click on add to cart (or) add to compare (or) add to wishlist *in category page* it is redirecting to homepage.But i want to remain in the same page.

It is working in another pages but it is not working in category page.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `System -> Configuration -> Sales tab -> Checkout`
Then under the `Shopping Cart` tab you can set the `After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart` to `No`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `system->configuration->checkout->Shoping Cart->After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart ->No

Comment: I don't recall any such setting in default Magento installation. Are you having some extension installed for this?

Comment: Go to `system->configuration->checkout->Shoping Cart->After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart ->No.....Sorry  Prateek,it should be like that